# Question about a catalytic equality?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have a question on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1221821/28555) that explains how I came up with these equations.

```
Reduce[n ∈ Integers && ((3^n - 1)/(2^n - 1)) - (3/2)^n < 1/2, {n}]
n ∈ Integers && Mod[((3^n - 1)/(2^n - 1)), 1] - Mod[(3/2)^n, 1]
== (3^n - 1)/(2^n - 1) - (3/2)^n // FullSimplify
```

From the `FullSimplify`
`n ∈ Integers && Floor[(3/2)^n] == Floor[(-1 + 3^n)/(-1 + 2^n)]`

I'd like to know if there is any simple explanation for this unexpected result.

Comment: It may help the reader if you specify your output, and what exactly you find unexpected in that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be correct:

```
 ins = n /. 
      FindInstance[Floor[(3/2)^n] == Floor[(-1 + 3^n)/(-1 + 2^n)] , n, 
          Integers, 20 ]
```

> {4811, 1040, 4155, 469, 4050, 733, 4039, 1415, 2799, 2403, 2571, 
>   4168, 252, 207, 4804, 2239, 4660, 535, 1603, 4756}

```
 (Mod[((3^# - 1)/(2^# - 1)), 1] - 
 Mod[(3/2)^#, 1] == (3^# - 1)/(2^# - 1) - (3/2)^#) & /@ ins
```

> { True,True, etc.. }

You can in fact readily derive this result if you simple substitute

```
                Mod[ arg, 1 ] -> arg - Floor[arg]
```

and Simplify.

Comment: +1, I had missed the simplification until you showed the last line. Thanks.